Unable to load application: NameError: uninitialized constant Polaris::ViewHelper
Upgrading my gem "polaris_view_components" from version "~> 1.2.0 to "2.0.0"
Gemfile
gem 'polaris_view_components', '~> 2.0', '>= 2.0.1'
gem "view_component"

Bundling gems was successful...
gem list polaris_view_components 

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

polaris_view_components (2.2.4)

But I cannot start the application, the error shows
Unable to load application: NameError: uninitialized constant Polaris::ViewHelper

There is NO trace of Polaris::ViewHelper in my source code (i don't include it manually).
It came from gem generated files (in the bottom part it contains helper Polaris::ViewHelper)
 /Users/developer/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/polaris_view_components-2.0.0/lib/polaris/view_components/engine.rb:36

Here is the file engine.rb
require "rails/engine"
require "view_component"
require "view_component/version"
  module Polaris
    module ViewComponents
      class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
        isolate_namespace Polaris::ViewComponents

        config.autoload_paths = %W[
          #{root}/app/components
          #{root}/app/helpers
        ]

        # Remove default wrapping .field_with_errors for proper Shopify form validations
        config.to_prepare do
          ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = ->(html_tag, _instance) { html_tag.html_safe }
        end

        initializer "polaris_view_components.assets" do |app|
          if app.config.respond_to?(:assets)
            app.config.assets.precompile += %w[
              polaris_view_components.js polaris_view_components.css
            ]
          end
        end

        initializer "polaris_view_components.importmap", before: "importmap" do |app|
          if app.config.respond_to?(:importmap) && app.config.importmap.has_key?(:cache_sweepers)
            app.config.importmap.cache_sweepers << Engine.root.join("app/assets/javascripts")
          end
        end

        initializer "polaris_view_components.helpers" do
          ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller_base) do
            helper Polaris::ViewHelper
            helper Polaris::UrlHelper
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end


Looks like the latest version of this gem is for Rails 7.1 or higher https://github.com/baoagency/polaris_view_components/pull/338/files
Also needs higher than ruby 3.1 - at least on my testing locally.
